# Where to add Maven dependencies in a multi-module Vaadin project in NetBeans 8?

Tags: maven, netbeans, vaadin, vaadin7

After creating a new [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.6.4 project in [NetBeans](http://www.NetBeans.org/) 8.1 using [Vaadin plugin for NetBeans](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans) and the provided [multi-module](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html) [archetype with 4 modules](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes), where does one add a dependency for adding libraries?

Is the `-ui` “Dependencies” the right place? Will that be inherited by the `-production` module? Or do I need to specify the dependency there too? Or anywhere else?

I am no Maven maven, not using the Maven command-line. I am using NetBeans own user-interface, adding dependencies by context-clicking in the `Projects` panel.

Comment: Dependencies are usually added in the pom.xml file for maven projects

Comment: This Question refers to multi-module projects with multiple POMs.

Comment: Yes, so you have multiple `pom.xml` files, just add the libs in the correct files. For example the widgetset and the parent won'usually don't need jar libraries.

Comment: "The correct files"? That is what I am asking.

Comment: What libraries are you adding? Probably in the pom.xml in the UI project is the correct one for general jar files like apache commons an similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is poorly documented. Agreed.

Yes, the `-ui` module is where you do all your work and add your dependencies (except Vaadin Add-ons). The `-production` module will automatically inherit `-ui` so you never actually change anything on the production module.

The `-widgetset` project is where Vaadin Add-on's should be added. However I don't do that directly, instead I use the Netbeans Vaadin Add-on Browser. This one you can activate from whatever module in your multi-module project, so even if you activate it on the `-ui` module it will figure out that you are adding a Vaadin Add-on and will add the dependency to the the POM on the `-widgetset` project, not the one module you right-clicked on. Sweet.

Also there's an annoying bug when you use the multi-module archetype which means that your generated WAR will be really large, for no good reason. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35406389/1504556. The fix is easy.

Comment: How does one activate the *Netbeans Vaadin Add-on Browser*? (and thanks for your helpful Answer)

Comment: @BasilBourque: Right-click the `-ui` project node in NetBeans. Then Vaadin --> Open Add-Ons Browser. All it really does is to allow you to search for Vaadin Add-Ons and then when selected it will change the POM for you. All of this you can do manually as well. It is just a nice convenience.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a very similar project. If you have parent and dependencies, maven inherits these dependencies from child to parent. So refer to each dependency in the base pom of the module that you need it in. An example would be:

> Module A needs dependency Z
>
> Module B needs dependency Y
>
> Module C needs dependency Z and Y

And your modules rely on:

> Parent needs A, B, C
>
> C needs B

So in B you would input the dependency of Y, in C you would need the dependency of B and Z, in A you would also need Z.

C doesn't need Y declaring as it has inherited it from B

The big issues you might get is dealing with cross inheritance, sometimes you need to tell certain modules to exclude some files that are inherited from other jar files, E.G old versions of files. You can this by:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

As an example. Hope that helps a little bit